# How to format input data for an conv1d/lstm nn in coreml converted from keras

Tags: keras, ios11, xcode9-beta, xcode9, coreml

My keras model with input shape (none, 40 [timesteps], 12 [features]) looks like this:

```swift
model = Sequential([
    Conv1D(nodes_per_layer, filter_length, subsample_length=2, activation='relu', input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim), name='accelerations'),
    Conv1D(nodes_per_layer, filter_length, subsample_length=1, activation='relu'),
    LSTM(nodes_per_layer, return_sequences=True),
    LSTM(nodes_per_layer, return_sequences=False),
    Dropout(dropout),
    Dense(num_classes),
    Activation('softmax', name='scores'),
])
```

After converting it to .mlmodel, I add it to my XCodeProject:
[image]

I then try to do inference and get prediction scores:

```swift
func makePredictionRequest(currentScaledMotionArrays: [[Double]]) {
    let data = _currentScaledMotionArrays.reduce([], +) //result is of type [Double] with 480 elements
    do {
        let mlMultiArray = try MLMultiArray(shape:[40,12], dataType:MLMultiArrayDataType.double)
        for (index, element) in data.enumerated() {
            mlMultiArray[index] = NSNumber(value: element)
        }
        let input = PredictionModelInput(accelerations: mlMultiArray)
        let predictionOutput = try _predictionModel.prediction(input: input)
    }
    catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

But the predictionModel.prediction(input: input) method always fails and throws the following error:

"The model expects input feature lstm_1_h_in to be an array, but the input is of type 0."

So hidden states of the lstm layers need to be initialized. I don't know if this behavior is expected, since I never faced the same problem before. Neither while doing inference in keras itself or with google cloud ml. I also don't know the initial values, which are usually chosen for inference. Maybe just arrays of zeros? Did anyone face a similar problem?

The .mlmodel file could be found [here](https://github.com/Lausbert/Exermote/tree/master/ExermoteInference/ExermoteCoreML/ExermoteCoreML/Model).

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: Stupid me, i just copied the code from apple documentation without actually catching the error. I changed my question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually achieved what I wanted to do.

The following snippet is working for **swift 4.0**, **keras 2.0.4** and **coremltools 0.4.0**.

The keras input shape is **(none, 40 [timesteps], 12 [features])**. Notice the changed parameter order **(40 [timesteps], none, 12 [features])** below.

The hidden stats of all 32 nodes of both lstm layers are initialized with zeros. I have to test if this will lead to expected behavior or if I have to initialize them randomly.

```swift
func makePredictionRequest(evaluationStep: EvaluationStep) {
        let data = _currentScaledMotionArrays.reduce([], +) //result is of type [Double] with 480 elements
        do {
            let accelerationsMultiArray = try MLMultiArray(shape:[40,1,12], dataType:MLMultiArrayDataType.double)
            for (index, element) in data.enumerated() {
                accelerationsMultiArray[index] = NSNumber(value: element)
            }
            let hiddenStatesMultiArray = try MLMultiArray(shape: [32], dataType: MLMultiArrayDataType.double)
            for index in 0..<32 {
                hiddenStatesMultiArray[index] = NSNumber(integerLiteral: 0)
            }
            let input = PredictionModelInput(accelerations: accelerationsMultiArray, lstm_1_h_in: hiddenStatesMultiArray, lstm_1_c_in: hiddenStatesMultiArray, lstm_2_h_in: hiddenStatesMultiArray, lstm_2_c_in: hiddenStatesMultiArray)
            let predictionOutput = try _predictionModel.prediction(input: input)
            print(predictionOutput.scores)
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

You can also see my [full implementation](https://github.com/Lausbert/Exermote/tree/master/ExermoteInference/ExermoteCoreML).

And if my answer solved your problem, just leave me an uptick here :)

Comment: How did the "zero" initialisation affect your outputs?

Comment: The classification works as expected (the .gif on my [projects front page](https://github.com/Lausbert/Exermote) actually shows this in use) and similar to my implementation on google cloud ml, where I didn't have to initialize anything. I have the feeling, that the initialization doesn't really matter as long as your sequence is long enough. But I have not tested random initialization so far.